# 特定のhtmlタグと特定の属性を許可する正規表現

Tags: php, 正規表現

特定のhtmlタグと、その中の特定の属性のみ許可する正規表現を試行錯誤しています。

タグに関しては、

【方法１】

```
preg_replace('/(?!<\/?(p|a|font)(>|\s[^>]*>))<("[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^\'">])*>/', '', $text);
```

【方法２】

```
htmlescape($text, array('p', '/p', 'a', '/a', 'font', '/font'));

function htmlescape($sValue, $arrAllowTag = array()) {
  $sValue = htmlspecialchars($sValue, ENT_QUOTES);
  if (count($arrAllowTag) == 0) return $sValue;
  foreach($arrAllowTag as $sTag) {
    if (strpos($sTag, '/') === false) {
      $sValue = preg_replace_callback("/&lt;\/?". $sTag . "( .*?&gt;|\/?&gt;)/i", "htmlescape_unhtmlescape", $sValue);
    }
  }
  return $sValue;
}

function htmlescape_unhtmlescape($sValue){
  $sString = $sValue[0];
  $sString = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $sString);
  $sString = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $sString);
  $sString = str_replace("&quot;", "\"", $sString);
  $sString = str_replace("&#039;", "'", $sString);
  return $sString;
}
```

といった方法で可能なのですが、許可されたhtmlタグの中の、更に特定の属性のみ許可する場合の正規表現がうまくいきません。
例えば

- <font>タグであれば、「color」属性のみ許可したい
- <p>タグであれば、「align」属性で、かつ値は「right」「left」「center」のみ許可したい

といった場合です。また、属性が現れる順番は保証されていません。

preg_replace_callbackなどを利用して効率の良い書き方があれば、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

タグを除くとき、削除するのかエスケープするのかは、どちらでも問題ありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己レスですが、【方法２】を弄って下記のように対応しました。
かなり泥臭いですが、目的は達成できるように思います。

```
$text = htmlescape($text, array('p', 'a', 'font', 'img'));

function htmlescape($sValue, $arrAllowTag = array()) {
  $sValue = htmlspecialchars($sValue, ENT_QUOTES);
  if (count($arrAllowTag) == 0) return $sValue;
  foreach($arrAllowTag as $sTag) {
    if (strpos($sTag, '/') === false) {
      $sValue = preg_replace_callback(sprintf("/&lt;(%s)(?:(?:&gt;|\s(.+)?&gt;).+?&lt;\/%s&gt;|.+?\/>)/i", $sTag, $sTag), "htmlescape_unhtmlescape", $sValue);
    }
  }
  return $sValue;
}

function htmlescape_unhtmlescape($aValue){
  $sOrigString = $aValue[0];
  $sTag = $aValue[1];
  $sAttributes = $aValue[2];

  $sAttributes = str_replace(array('&quot;', '&#039;', '&lt;', '&gt;'), '', $sAttributes);
  $sAttributes = str_replace(array("\"", "'"), '', $sAttributes);
  $aParams = explode(' ', $sAttributes);

  $bError = false;

  switch($sTag) {
    case 'p':
      if(!$sAttributes) break;
      $aAlignParams = array('right', 'left', 'center');
      foreach($aParams as $sAttr) {
        list($sKey, $sVal) = explode('=', $sAttr);
        /*
          $sKeyと$sValの値をチェックして、意図しない値であれば
          $bError = true;
          break;
        */
      }
      break;
    case 'font':
    /*
      その他タグも同様にチェック
    */
  }

  if($bError === false) {
    $sOrigString = htmlspecialchars_decode($sOrigString);
  }
  return $sOrigString;
}
```